# Extracted thumbnail from DNG image using DCRaw

Tags: c#, thumbnails, dng, dcraw

I am using DCRaw as a command line utility to extract thumbnails from DNG images. The thumbnail colors are way off and inverting them will not help.

I took a photo with my Camera and the preview looks like this:
[image]

Here is how I call DCRAW:

```
 Settings oSettings = Settings.GetInstance();
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(dcRawPath)
 {
    Arguments = "-e \"" + sInputFileName + "\"",
    UseShellExecute = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WorkingDirectory = RootDirectory
 };
 var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

The result ppm file looks like this:
[image]

I tried inverting the thumbnail using this code:

```
static readonly ColorMatrix _inverseColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new[]
{
   new float[] {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
   new float[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}
});

public static Bitmap InverseImage(Bitmap source)
{
   var newBitmap = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);
   using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
   {
      var attributes = new ImageAttributes();
      attributes.SetColorMatrix(_inverseColorMatrix);
      g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
                            0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
   }

   return newBitmap;
}
```

This gave me the thumbnail like so:

[image]

I got the same result using Photoshop which means that the code is inverting the image correctly but it seems that this is not the way to parse DNG thumbnails.

How can I invert the thumbnail generated by DCRaw to give the correct colors much like the first image.

Note: my camera is a Lumia 1020 with DNG output.

EDIT: The original DNG file can be downloaded from [Here](http://1drv.ms/1Pi3b2c)

Comment: Can you post or send me the file? I've just begun writing DNG support in my imaging library. If the file is valid, I could write a thumbnail extractor as a command line utility. (bitbank@pobox.com).

Comment: @BitBank I don't have the file ATM will put a link to it probably tomorrow. However, I tried this with several other dng files and the extracted thumbnail from dcraw looks fine with no need to adjust or invert colors. It seems that this issue is related to Lumia 1020 which is a bummer since most of the images that I want to process are taken with that phone. So it seems it needs some special treatment.

Comment: Either it needs special treatment or it's a bug in DCRaw...

Comment: @BitBank I added a link to the original DNG file

Comment: I looked at your file and one I made with my Lumia 1520. There's nothing wrong with DCRaw; it's writing the uncompressed color preview image exactly as it is. The uncompressed thumbnail in your file has the "purple spot" problem that sometimes occurs with smartphone camera software. The raw image data, when properly balanced, looks correct. You can see this "purple spot" issue on many smartphones when the light level is low.

Comment: @BitBank I am not convinced by this. All the thumbnails that come from that camera have the exact same color profile. The preview image and the DNG itself look fine yet only the thumbnail have this weird saturation. Evident by the images in my original post you can see the difference between the DNG file and the thumbnail. If this was in fact the purple spot issue, then the DNG, thumbnail and low-res image would all have the same effect.

Comment: Whatever the cause, the problem does not lie with DCRaw. The Lumia 1020 is writing that color information to its preview image. The preview image is an uncompressed RGB bitmap. There's no other way to interpret the data. Does it really surprise you that there's a bug in Windows Phone software?